# Not showing statistics for Daily active user and Monthly active user is Google play console

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, google-play-console

I have good user base in google play store. The Daily active user and Monthly active user is not showing any data and its showing as Data unavailable. Any idea I am missing anything ? Do I need to enable anything to get this data ?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic

Answer (score 0):

It is mostly likely that your DAU is below 100 [image]